# Issues installing Ubuntu 12.04 on ASUS A46 CM

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, asus

I never had success installing Ubuntu 12.04_2 64bit on my ASUS A46 CM, can someone help me? it's always rebooting and never starts after selecting language option. I'm downloading from ubuntu server 1,6 GB and 700MB also.

ASUS A46CM spec:

- Intel Core i5 3317U 1.7 - turbo boost 2.6 GHz
- RAM 4 GB
- VGA nVidia 635m 2 GB.
- Sonic Master Audio
- HDD 500 GB

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar machine (http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.M3AAA.006) on which I successfully booted ubuntu12.04. Below are the steps I did. Hope it helps you too. This machine has UEFI secure booting enabled.

a) Create a USB bootable for 12.04 (64-bit) from ISO in ubuntu website. Follow the steps provided in ubuntu website for creating a UEFI bootable disk.

b) Insert the pendive, enter BIOS and add the UEFI keys into it. Change the boot order to choose the new UEFI key (its grubxxx.efi)

c) Boot to ubuntu on pendrive and then partition the hard-disk as the installer asks.

d) When you reboot to boot to ubuntu on HDD, please enter the BIOS, and perform the same procedure to add the keys from ubuntu partition, and boot order.

e) I half-successfully booted ubuntu 12.04. Half-successfully because the grub isnt stable and cannot dual boot WIN8 and Ubuntu together. I have to change the boot order in BIOS everytime I need to switch OS. I am working to fix that now.

But I hope this helps you.